# Salesforce Chat button rendered multiple times in Angular application

Tags: liveagent, chat, embedded-services

We are trying to embed **Salesforce Chat** into our Angular based application. To do this, we got the embedded code snippets (*Chat Code Snippet* and *Meta Tag Code Snippet*) from Salesforce *Setup*, under *Embedded Service Deployments*

**URI:** /lightning/setup/EmbeddedServiceDeployments/home

We are trying to load the script dynamically in root component of our Angular application. But the chat button is rendered four times. We tried by adding this embedded script into constructor / ngOnInit. But still the chat button is rendered multiple time even though the constructor or ngOnInit block is executed only once.

As shown in below screenshot of Developer Tools, the embedded script is repeated four times instead of once.

[image]

Please advise how to fix this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated question with further details